# Why does WordPress use global variables?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, global

I am Korean.
I'm not good at English. I'm sorry.

Why does WordPress use global variables?

I want to know why I am using global variables such as global $ post in WordPress

I use a lot of global variables in WordPress.
What are the advantages?

If you use a lot of global variables, it seems to have problems such as hiding, readability, etc.? is not it?

In some ways, I want to know if a wordpress or woocommerce plugin is using a lot of global variables

Using global variables in woocommerce template file, is there a better way ??

Comment: Wordpress isn't exactly a great example of great code. It's as bad as it seems.

Comment: If you want to identify global vars, do a call to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php at the end of your script in the global scope.  You can always test if a view really does have global scope by creating a variable inside it and using that method.

Comment: It's mostly because Wordpress sucks.  If you want to learn industry best practice then Wordpress is a vital teaching aid.  Just look at the codebase and do the exact opposite of what the Wordpress developers did.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress code is most of based on hooks, action/filters

Now for each hook, we as WP developer, we need to do some code for functionality. So for example, if we are coding on some page, than we need to get page id for fetching all meta data.

So for this there are 3 choices.

1. Pass them in hook as arguments
2. Declare them as global variables
3. Set them in session

First approach is not advisable as we need to pass too many data in argument.

Second approach, we are using now.

Third approach is not advisable as some data need to be changes very frequently.

So best approach is for global variables, which WordPress is using.

Let me know if any part is unclear...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150708/discussion-on-answer-by-wildprogrammers-why-does-wordpress-use-global-variables).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to explain it is that it's the WordPress way of activating Wordpress methods inside of a function.

For example, in functions.php:

```
function someFunction{   global $wpdb }
```

Allows you to use all the functionality of the `$wpdb` object.